# Suspend delayed after lid close

Tags: systemd, suspend, acpi, sleep

For some reason, when I close my laptop lid, it takes my system 25 seconds to sleep. This is without any autolock prorams (xss-lock, xautolock, etc.) running. In my `journalctl` I can see exactly a 25 second delay between the lid close event and the "Starting TLP suspend/resume" event. Where could I even begin to look to diagnose this? Just yesterday, it took less than 3 seconds for my laptop to sleep. Now, after playing around with some of my window manager settings, it's jumped to 25. I've undone all the changes that I've made recently and still can't figure out what's going on. I've double checked that I don't have any services running through systemd that might interfere with the sleep.

Edit: So after some more digging, I've disabled as much as I can on my laptop to try and diagnose this. I've gotten to the point where in `journalctl` there are no log entries between the lid closed message and the 'starting sleep' message. However, there is still a 25 second delay. I'm even more confused than before.

Comment: May be you can start diagnose with file /etc/systemd/logind.conf

Comment: I've looked there, the only thing not commented out is the line to enable suspend on lid close.

Comment: Please try to run `systemd-analyze blame` (perhaps also as root) after you wake up again, perhaps that can tell you something. This is usually the way to analyse delays in `systemd` processes.

Comment: Running that tells me that NetworkManager-wait-online.service took 6.341s to load, postgresql took 2.2, bolt took 1.6, and everything else was under a second. Nothing close to the 25 second dolay I'm seeing.

Comment: I can't see how `systemd-analyze blame` that is for boot performance would help with diagnosing suspend delay. @theasianpianist did you ever get to the bottom of the issue? I am experiencing the same after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 :/
One clue I found is that using `pm-suspend` is almost instantaneous so it's `systemd` related...

Comment: @Cas unfortunately not, I ended up doing a full reinstall of Ubuntu (for unrelated reasons). Sorry :(